# "Leaf-justify" D3 tree graphs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What do I need to do to get tree graphs to render such that nodes are justified towards the leaf side of the graph?

I'd like to take an arbitrary tree graph that might normally look like:

[image: before]

and have it come out similar to:

[image: after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to discover the depth of the tree and set the `depth` property of each node that doesn't have any children to that value.

Assuming your tree data is as follows:

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "Top Level",
        "parent": "null",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Level 2: A",
                "parent": "Top Level",
                "children": [ ...
```

And you created a tree using:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree();
```

You can get the `depth` of the tree by searching each node for the max value of `depth`:

```
var treeDepth = d3.max(tree(data[0]), function(d) { return d.depth; });
```

Once you have that, you can reset it every time you recompute the tree layout:

```
tree.nodes(data[0]).forEach(function(d) {
    var depthSize = 50;
    if (!d.children) { // this node has no children
        d.depth = treeDepth; // set depth to depth of tree
    }
    d.y = d.depth * depthSize; // recalculate y
});
```

This works for trees laid out as in your example (from left to right). For top-down layouts you have to change `d.x` instead.

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Ltg4etrs/)** with a working solution adapted from **[this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)**.

Comment: I realize I didn't explain this, but I needed all nodes "leaf-justified", such that all nodes have a largest possible depth that is smaller than their shallowest child. Your code pointed me in the right direction so I was able to make modifications as seen in [this fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/muufvf40/).